# Mini-pages and image urls

Tags: meteor

I've recently started to use mini-pages for my client-side routing and all has been going well. However, once my url route gets 2 or more levels deep the image urls get messed up.

For example if I am at my root location at say, test.com/
The image url correctly is displayed as test.com/image.png

When the url is test.com/test,
the image url correctly is displayed as test.com/image.png

However, when the url is 2 levels deep such as test.com/test/viewall,
the image url is incorrectly displayed as test.com/test/image.png

The last example causes my images not to be displayed on the 2 levels or deeper pages. How do I address this issue?

Comment: Just as a note, you should switch to https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router for your Meteor router; this is a new joint project by the author of mini-pages and the other popular meteor router, so it's the de facto official router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using relative addresses, rather than absolute.  Try prefixing with /, see where you need to put images for that, then putting all images there.  You can still nest, just in absolute terms rather than relative (start with a /)

Comment: Oh my... I think I need some sleep :p. My head was about to burst from annoyance... Thank you!